# Фильтровать массив по значению ключа в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
const arr = [
  {a: 'a', b: 'b'}, 
  {a: null, b: 'b'},
  {a: 'a', b: null}
];
```

Как его отфильтровать, чтобы на выходе получился массив только с теми элементами, у которых нет null в значении ключа?

Т.е. применив фильтр, получать [{a: 'a', b: 'b'}]

Comment: Не совсем понятно условие. Предоставьте желаемый результат для вашего примера входных данных.

Comment: Я бы сказал, судя по условию, что на выходе должен быть пустой массив, поскольку есть такие объекты в массиве, где и a и b === null.

Comment: @smellyshovel  обновил вопрос и добавил желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что-то вроде такого. Хотя условие понятно не до конца.

```js
const arr = [
  {a: 'a', b: 'b'}, 
  {a: null, b: 'b'},
  {a: 'a', b: null}
];


const res = arr.filter((obj) => {
  return !Object.keys(obj).some((key) => {
    return obj[key] === null;
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Нужно, что бы возвращалось {a: 'a', b: 'b'}

Comment: @overus обновил ответ. Так?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Решение работает как надо.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const arr = [
  {a: 'a', b: 'b'}, 
  {a: null, b: 'b'},
  {a: 'a', b: null}
];

const needToExclude = null;

let newArr = arr.filter((obj) => !Object.values(obj).some((el) => el === needToExclude));
console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Это решение не то, что вам нужно, убирает только свойства со значениями null, а не весь элемент массива

```
arr.map(item => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function (key) {
            if (item[key] === null) {
                delete (item[key])
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Вам подходит этот вариант

```
arr.filter((obj) => !Object.values(obj).some(el => el === null))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: el === null, лучше !el

Comment: я так не думаю...
в значениях свойств может быть undefined, пустая строка, 0, false. 
Не написано в задании, что их тоже нужно фильтровать.  Нужно оставить те, у которых нет именно null в значении

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  { a: "a", b: "b" },
  { a: null, b: "b" },
  { a: "a", b: null }
];

const res = arr.map((obj) => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    const element = obj[key];
    if (obj[key] == null) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
});
```